How to click and loop through html with Selenium Webdriver/Python with no hyperlink
I'm new to scraping and am trying to get the available apartments and their accompanying information from this website (https://sightmap.com/embed/rx1p8y12vd6). Logically, I'm trying to have selenium click through each floor and then pull the dynamic information from each floor (Apt Number, Rent, etc.). The carousel has all the floors in the below format:
<li id="floor-item-42349" role="option" aria-selected="false" aria-label="Floor 21 selected, 1 of 19 stories. 2 Units available." tabindex="-1" class="css-1ge3v7g-itemStyles"><span class="primary-font css-1an6fko-floorStyles">21</span><span class="css-1cygnfi-countStyles"><span class="css-1gmg8q9-numberStyles">2</span><span class="css-1c0jwqn-unitLabelStyles">Units</span></span></li>

Previously, I've seen solutions which have a href to click on which makes it possible, but I don't see where this could be. I'm not familiar with how aria-labels work so maybe this is the key?
Below is what I am working with currently but the click doesn't seem to work.
floors = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#floor-vertical-select > li ")))
 for floor in floors:
     if floor.text != "0":
         print("Floor: " + floor.text)
         floor.click()


We meet again... :)
This one is the same basic concept as the last one, just needed updated locators.

Loop through the floors across the left of the page.
If the number of units available is not 0, then print the floor and available unit count, then click it.
Loop through each available unit in the right panel and print it.

The working code is below.
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

#url = f'file:///C:/Users/jbcro/Desktop/sample.html'
url = 'https://sightmap.com/embed/rx1p8y12vd6'
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get(url)

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

floors = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#floor-vertical-select span[class*='numberStyles']")))
for floor in floors:
    if floor.text != "0":
        print("Floor: " + driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#floor-vertical-select span[class*='floorStyles']").text + ", Available units: " + floor.text)
        floor.click()
        for unit in wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "ul[data-testid='unit-list'] li"))):
            print(unit.text)
            print("")
        print("")


You can use their API endpoint to get those details easily,
API endpoint: https://sightmap.com/app/api/v1/rx1p8y12vd6/sightmaps/14338
Sample code:
import requests

url = 'https://sightmap.com/app/api/v1/rx1p8y12vd6/sightmaps/14338'

resp = requests.get(url).json()
for i in resp['data']['floors']:
    ids = i['id']
    label = i['filter_label']
    for unit in resp['data']['units']:
        if ids in unit['floor_id']:
            plan_id = unit['floor_plan_id']
            for plan in resp['data']['floor_plans']:
                if plan_id in plan['id']:
                    print(f"-----------------------\nDisplay are: {unit['display_area']}\nDisplay unit no: {unit['display_unit_number']} {plan['name']}\nDisplay term: {unit['display_lease_term']}\nAvailable: {unit['display_available_on']}\nDisplay price: {unit['display_price']}\nFloor no: {label}\nBed rooms: {plan['bedroom_count']}\nBath rooms: {plan['bathroom_count']}")

Output:
-----------------------
Display are: 1,158 sq. ft.
Display unit no: APT 1112 T-A9
Display term: 15 Months
Available: Available Jan 17th
Display price: $4,071
Floor no: Floor 11
Bed rooms: 1
Bath rooms: 1
-----------------------
Display are: 917 sq. ft.
Display unit no: APT 1201 T-A8
Display term: 15 Months
Available: Available Feb 28th
Display price: $3,141
Floor no: Floor 12
Bed rooms: 1
Bath rooms: 1
-----------------------
Display are: 789 sq. ft.
Display unit no: APT 1203 T-A5
Display term: 10 Months
Available: Available Dec 6th
Display price: $2,519
Floor no: Floor 12
Bed rooms: 1
Bath rooms: 1
-----------------------
Display are: 600 sq. ft.
Display unit no: APT 1304 T-S1
Display term: 13 Months
Available: Available Jan 27th
Display price: $2,317
Floor no: Floor 13
Bed rooms: 0
Bath rooms: 1
-----------------------
Display are: 789 sq. ft.
Display unit no: APT 1402 T-A4
Display term: 15 Months
Available: Available Feb 7th
Display price: $2,571
Floor no: Floor 14
Bed rooms: 1
Bath rooms: 1

